# PHP 5 to PHP 7 transpiler

Tags: php, migration, php-5.6, php-7.2, transpiler

I have a big project in php 5 and it's well documented. Now, I want to migrate to php 7.2 and I have already checked the compatibility using phpstan and every thing is alright. So, I wonder if there is a tool that could automatically transform the php 5 annotations to php 7 (like functions declarations and variables )?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show examples of what you want to convert.  Annotations aren't something which I would have thought are directly related to the version of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from php-cs-fixer, also have a look at [Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector). It offers much more advanced rules and allows you to create your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to convert phpdoc param types to typehints, you can use [php-cs-fixer](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer) that includes this kind of feature : [phpdoc_to_param_type](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:3.0%7Cfixer:phpdoc_to_param_type)

There is also a fixer for function return types : [phpdoc_to_return_type](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/#version:3.0%7Cfixer:phpdoc_to_return_type)

Example from the php-cs-fixer documentation :

```
<?php

/** @param string|null $bar */
function my_foo($bar)
{}
```

will become

```
<?php

/** @param string|null $bar */
function my_foo(?string $bar)
{}
```

beware, those features are tagged as experimental so you should always double check what has been done.

Comment: Thanks man. This is kind of what I am looking for. So I will try it. Is there any thing like that for variables?